# Why we are giving Q_OBJECT in private section only?

Tags: qt, private, public, qobject

Why we usually give Q_OBJECT in private section only?
I tried a sample program by giving it in public section ,I found no difference.
If anybody knows can you tell me the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the `Q_OBJECT` macro expands to:

```
#define Q_OBJECT \
public: \
    Q_OBJECT_CHECK \
    static const QMetaObject staticMetaObject; \
    Q_OBJECT_GETSTATICMETAOBJECT \
    virtual const QMetaObject *metaObject() const; \
    virtual void *qt_metacast(const char *); \
    QT_TR_FUNCTIONS \
    virtual int qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void **); \
private: \
    Q_DECL_HIDDEN static const QMetaObjectExtraData staticMetaObjectExtraData; \
    Q_DECL_HIDDEN static void qt_static_metacall(QObject *, QMetaObject::Call, int, void **);
```

at least on mine Qt 4.8, so you can see that it switches to `public` visibility level to declare the needed functions and the back to `private` in order to ensure that nothing is broken. So if you declare your `Q_OBJECT` in a `public` section you might have the funny consequence that things after are not public anymore :)

Comment: That means if we give in public section nothing will happen.

Comment: I actually have edited my answer, if you declare it in the public section it will switch to private afterwards

Comment: Wow that's amazing..HatsUp to C++

Answer (score 3):

If you put Q_OBJECT under public identifier, all your public declaration will become private. For example:

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{    
public:
    Q_OBJECT

    Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0); // <- now declared as private
```